# How to Create a "BoxShape" in jBullet?

Tags: java, parameters, jbullet

I want to create a **BoxShape** in jBullet. The constructor asks for a ***Vector3f*** object as parameter which asks for three **float** parameters.

```
BoxShape(Vector3f boxHalfExtends) //The constructor for the "BoxShape" class.
```

I have looked at the jBullet page and couldn't find what ***boxHalfExtends*** is.

What am I supposed to enter to the **constructor parameter** for the **BoxShape**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "To create a box you have to pass a vector with the half-extents."

Source: http://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Bullet_Collision_Shapes

What that means is, you need to pass in half of the width and height for the box on the **x,y,z** axises.

```
float dx = 0.5f; //X Width = 0.5 * 2 = dx - (-dx) = 1
float dy = 0.5f; //Y Width = 0.5 * 2 = dy - (-dy) = 1
float dz = 1.0f; //Z Width = 1.0 * 2 = dz - (-dz) = 2

CollisionObject boxShape = BoxShape(Vector3f(dx, dy, dz));
```

The **dx,dy,dz** values aren't about where on the world the box is placed but how big it is.